# rbind complete rows every two column from single Data frame

Tags: r

i need a guidance in one of my Task : here i need to rbind [complete row] the every two columns where the total number of columns are varying[any even No of Columns] depending on the dataset Browse and uploaded by user. Similar to image i have uploaded along with the Text,Basically we can say we are stacking every two column one above other and creating a new data frame which has two column as shown in Figure , Thank you well in advance

[image: converted to two column all rows are one above other]

Comment: If you are seeking the multiple column names in different rows, it would not be useful

Comment: @akrun Appreciate you answer Sir actually after this i will be merging with another data frame for further computation , for that Purpose i am approaching this way. i tried with column wise merging after every 2nd column the size of keeps on enlarging and in this case No of rows will be increased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We `split` the dataset by the character substring of the column names (remove the numbers with `gsub`) into a `list`, change the `names` of the `list` with `setNames` and `rbind` the `list` elements to a single `data.table` using `rbindlist` and specifying the `idcol` as 'Tag'

```
library(data.table)
lst <- split.default(df1, gsub("\\d+", "", names(df1)))
#or use
#lst <- split.default(df1, cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol(df1)/2)))

rbindlist(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)), idcol="Tag")
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10*8), ncol=8,
    dimnames = list(NULL, paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 2), 0:1))))
```

Comment: this Code worked for Me :                                                                          lst <- split.default(df, cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol(df)/2)))
c<-rbindlist(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)), idcol="Tag")                                                       Appreciate your Answere sir !

Comment: How can we cbind from DF-02 to DF-01 depending Tag as shown in above question but this time we need DF-02 to DF-01 .Thank you well in advance

Comment: @NabiShaikh  Not sure I understand your question.  Perhaps `rbindlist(setNames(lst[rev(names(lst))], rev(seq_along(lst))), idcol="Tag")`

Comment: sir , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228187/cbind-complete-rows-depending-on-tag-no-1-to-maxtag-no

Comment: How can we use same code for rbinding required no of column Let say first 4 column or 5 column or 6 column .Thank you well in advance.`lst <- split.default(df1, cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol(df1)/2)))` this is for 2 column rbinding similarly how can we do for any required number of column rbinding.basically I want to understand the code

Comment: @NabiShaikh  It will bind 'n' number of columns

Comment: i have used `lst <- split.default(df1, cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol(df1)/2)))` for combining every 2 column earlier But can we use the same code for bind 4 column ..Basically what i am Looking is i want to understand `cumsum(TRUE,FALSE)` because their is always a requirement where i need to rbind any no of column ,so requesting you to plz explain on this..Thnk you sir

Comment: @NabiShaikh  Try `split.default(df1, cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), length.out = ncol(df1))))`

Comment: i am unable understand this `cumsum(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)` can you plz explain on this `let say for example i have to combine every 5 column ` Basically i want understand Please explain it will be helpful especially `(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)`  how you decide the sequence ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a `reshape` operation if you rename your columns to group appropriately:

```
names(df1) <- gsub("(.)(.)", "\\2.\\1", names(df1))
reshape(df1, direction="long", varying=TRUE, sep=".", timevar="Tag")

#     Tag            0           1 id
#1.A    A -0.545880758 -1.31690812  1
#2.A    A  0.536585304  0.59826911  2
#3.A    A  0.419623149 -0.76221437  3
#4.A    A -0.583627199 -1.42909030  4
#5.A    A  0.847460017  0.33224445  5
#6.A    A  0.266021979 -0.46906069  6
#7.A    A  0.444585270 -0.33498679  7
#8.A    A -0.466495124  1.53625216  8
#9.A    A -0.848370044  0.60999453  9
#10.A   A  0.002311942  0.51633570 10
#1.B    B -0.074308561 -0.03373792  1
#2.B    B -0.605156946 -0.58542756  2
# ...
```

Using @akrun's `df1`

Comment: @akrun's , Here we have rbinded every 2 column `what if we want to rbind 4 Columns instead of 2 column`

Comment: @akrun Earlier what we have done is `rbinding 2 columns` and what  `if we rbind after every four column` Thank you well in advance sir